# How to covert row wise data to column wise based on certain conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2007

I have an excel, which has exam data (Theory, Sessional, Practical etc ) row wise. I have to put same QPCODE based data in single row.
My data are-

```
 +-------+--------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
    |  id   | qpcode | subject_paper_code | subject_code |       subject_name        | subject_paper_name | subject_paper_short_code | subject_paper_group | min_marks | max_marks |
    +-------+--------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
    | 37790 |  10032 |                  0 | A47          | GEOGRAPHY                 | THEORY             | GEOG1                    | A                   |        21 |        60 |
    | 37791 |        |                  1 | A47          | GEOGRAPHY                 | I.A.(THEORY)       | GE1IA                    | A                   |         0 |        10 |
    | 37792 |        |                  2 | A47          | GEOGRAPHY                 | PRACTICAL          | GE1PR                    | B                   |         9 |        20 |
    | 37793 |        |                  3 | A47          | GEOGRAPHY                 | RECORD             | GE1RC                    | B                   |         0 |        10 |
    | 37794 |  10033 |                  0 | A50          | HINDI (OPT)               | THEORY             | HINO1                    | A                   |        40 |        80 |
    | 37795 |        |                  1 | A50          | HINDI (OPT)               | I.A.(THEORY)       | HI1IA                    | A                   |         0 |        20 |
    | 37796 |  10034 |                  0 | A51          | HISTORY(PRIOR TO 2008-09) | THEORY             | HIST1                    | A                   |        40 |        80 |
    +-------+--------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have to put same qpcode data in single row, so that i can get same qpcode data in single row for all qpcodes.

```
+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+
|  id   | qpcode | subject_paper_code | subject_code | subject_name | subject_paper_name | subject_paper_short_code | subject_paper_group | min_marks | max_marks | subject_paper_short_code2 | min_marks2 | max_marks2 | subject_paper_short_code3 | min_marks3 | max_marks3 | subject_paper_short_code4 | min_marks4 | max_marks4 |
+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+
| 37790 |  10032 |                  0 | A47          | GEOGRAPHY    | THEORY             | GEOG1                    | A                   |        21 |        60 | GE1IA                     |          0 |         10 | GE1PR                     |          9 |         20 | GE1RC                     |          0 |         10 |
+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA to do this is simpler. But I wanted to see if it can be done using PivotTable. So here are the four steps I've followed.

**Step 1: Cleaning the data**

1. Copy your data to a new sheet.
2. There are a few unnecessary columns. Remove them:

   - id
   - subject_paper_code
   - subject_code
   - subject_name
   - subject_paper_name
   - subject_paper_group

They don't serve any purpose in the summary, and are rather inappropriate as they pertain to a specific record. However, if you do want those, you can use a simple `VLOOKUP` to get those afterwards.

After you delete those columns, you'll be left with four. Assume these are contained in columns `A:D`.

3. You'll need a helper column that'll replace the original `qpcode` column, so that the question paper codes are continuous and don't have any blank cells between them.

For that, you can insert a column to the left of column A (containing the `qpcode`), paste this formula in `A2` and drag it down:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),A1,B2)
```

This will make the qpcodes repeat for each record.

4. Copy that column and paste it as value. Delete the original `qpcode` column (column B) that contains only one code for every set of records.

Your sheet should look like this:

```
╔════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ qpcode ║ subject_paper_short_code ║ min_marks ║ max_marks ║
╠════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║  10032 ║ GEOG1                    ║        21 ║        60 ║
║  10032 ║ GE1IA                    ║         0 ║        10 ║
║  10032 ║ GE1PR                    ║         9 ║        20 ║
║  10032 ║ GE1RC                    ║         0 ║        10 ║
║  10033 ║ HINO1                    ║        40 ║        80 ║
║  10033 ║ HI1IA                    ║         0 ║        20 ║
║  10034 ║ HIST1                    ║        40 ║        80 ║
╚════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

**Step 2: Creating the PivotTable**

1. Create a PivotTable
2. Drag the `qpcode` onto the Rows area
3. Drag these fields one by one in this order onto the Columns area

   - subject_paper_short_code
   - min_marks
   - max_marks
4. Use the following settings on all three of the fields that you placed in the Columns area in the previous step

   - Click on the field; choose 'Field Settings'
   - Choose `None` in the `Subtotals & Filters` tab
   - Go to the `Layout & Print` tab and check the `Repeat item labels` option

*Note: Applying the settings in the previous step is required only for the first two items in the Columns area. Applying them to the third (`max_marks`) makes no difference.*

5. Drag these onto the Values area as well (these are the same ones you placed in Columns area in the previous step):

   - subject_paper_short_code
   - min_marks
   - max_marks
6. Choose the 'Count' option in 'Summarize value field by' setting. This is required only to make the cleaning part a bit easier at the end.

**Step 3: Manipulating the Results**

1. Copy the PivotTable and in a new sheet, paste it using 'Paste as Values' in 'Paste Special' option
2. Copy the Column and Row labels from the copy of PivotTable, and paste it below. Here's a screenshot to make it clearer:

[image: Copy of PivotTable]

*I've boldened the column headings.*

3. Paste this formula in `B10`, and copy it to the entire range (in this case, `B10:V12`):

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B5)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MOD(COLUMN()-1,3)+3*(MOD(COLUMN()-1,3)=0),COLUMN())))
```

Keep this range selected for the next instructions.

4. Copy this range again, and paste it as values (in the same location).
5. With the range still selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (Replace dialog), and replace `FALSE` with blanks.
6. Press <kbd>F5</kbd>, and choose `Goto Special`. Then, select `Blank` cells option and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now, only the blank cells within the range will be selected.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and from the dialog that pops up, choose `Shift cells left`.

**Step 4: Cleaning up**

- Notice the 'Count of ' prefixed to the column headings. Select the row and replace `Count of` (including a trailing space) with blank.
- Replace the `Row Label` with `qpcode`.
- A few additional columns will remain at the end. Delete them as well.

That's it. That should leave you with the data you need.

Here's the output from the data you provided:

```
╔════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ qpcode ║ subject_paper_short_code ║ min_marks ║ max_marks ║ subject_paper_short_code ║ min_marks ║ max_marks ║ subject_paper_short_code ║ min_marks ║ max_marks ║ subject_paper_short_code ║ min_marks ║ max_marks ║
╠════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║  10032 ║ GE1IA                    ║         0 ║        10 ║ GE1PR                    ║         9 ║        20 ║ GE1RC                    ║         0 ║        10 ║ GEOG1                    ║        21 ║        60 ║
║  10033 ║ HI1IA                    ║         0 ║        20 ║ HINO1                    ║        40 ║        80 ║                          ║           ║           ║                          ║           ║           ║
║  10034 ║ HIST1                    ║        40 ║        80 ║                          ║           ║           ║                          ║           ║           ║                          ║           ║           ║
╚════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```